# How to loop over images in my app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I m trying to set images. It works fine when I set the first image, but when I try to upload a second image, it creates a second image box, but does not display anything on it, instead displays it on top of the first image box. I want them to be separate from each other.

I have tried to use blob directly by returning imgUrl (return imgUrl) in showImage function, but it also does not set blob in img src.
How can I loop over and set all images separately in each box as soon as pic (URL) is received?

```
class Card extends Component {
  constructor({props, pic, token}) {
    super(props, pic, token);
    this.state = { 
      pic: pic
    };

readResponseAsBlob(response) {
  return response.blob();
}

validateResponse(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw Error(response.statusText);
  }
  return response;
}

logError(error) {
  console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
}

showImage(responseAsBlob) {
  var container = document.getElementById('images');
  var imgElem = container.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  var imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(responseAsBlob);
  imgElem.src = imgUrl;
  console.log(imgUrl);
}


  urlFetch(data) {
   fetch(data, { 
   headers: new Headers({
     'authorization': `Bearer ${this.props.token}`, 
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  })
    .then(this.validateResponse)
    .then(this.readResponseAsBlob)
    .then(this.showImage)
    .catch(this.logError);
  }


  render() {
    const { pic } = this.state;

return (
             <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} className='tc dib br3 ma2 pa2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
              <div id='images'>
               <img style={{width: 175, height: 175}} className='tc myimage br3' alt='none' src={ this.urlFetch(pic) }/>
              </div>
              </a>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm blind, but I don't see any loops for generating image boxes. Is it in another class? If so, can you show it?

Comment: @LeoOdishvili image boxes are created when 'pic' which contains URL are recieved from another component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be here `src={ this.urlFetch(pic) }` The function `urlFetch` is returning a promise instead of actual image path or data.
Call this function in `componentDidMount` hook and the set the image you receive from backend in state and use that state property as `src` of image.

I can see that `urlFetch` function manually modifying the DOM to set the image src, this is sort of confusing since the function you are calling is doing its job implicitly and modifying DOM in react is not a good practice at all and `var imgElem = container.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];` will only modify the first image since you are getting the first `img` in the container

I would also suggest to render each image in their respective component declare a state property which will hold the `src` of image, fetch the image of server and then update the state.

```
class Card extends Component {

  constructor({props, token}) {
    super(props, token);
    this.state = { 
      src: ''
    };
  }

 readResponseAsBlob = (response) => {
  return response.blob();
 }

showImage = (responseAsBlob) => {
this.setState({ src: URL.createObjectURL(responseAsBlob) });
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.urlFetch(this.props.pic)
  }

  logError(error) {
    console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
  }

  urlFetch(data) {
    fetch(data, { 
    headers: new Headers({
       'authorization': `Bearer ${this.props.token}`, 
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    })
    .then(this.validateResponse)
    .then(this.readResponseAsBlob)
    .then(this.showImage)
    .catch(this.logError);
  }


  render() {
    const { src } = this.state;

    return (
      <a style={{width: 200, height: 250}} className='tc dib br3 ma2 pa2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
        <div id='images'>
          <img style={{width: 175, height: 175: display: src ? 'block': 'none'}} className='tc myimage br3' alt='none' src={ src }/>
        </div>
      </a>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer with example @TedKhi, also when you pass something to component they will only receive them in props and not as separate argument for constructor

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at readResponseAsBlob

Comment: Removing the bind from promise and using arrow function in readResponseAsBlob works.

readResponseAsBlob = (response) => {
    this.setState({src: response.blob()});
    console.log(this.state.src)
  }

Comment: But there is a problem. It does not update the src with blob URL. src contains size and mime type value only. You can see it in the console log. And so it does not display any image.

Comment: I actually cannot run this locally, can you paste the response in question?

Comment: I think you forgot to add showImage function from my question.
This is the console log of your answer: .......

Promise {<pending>}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
Blob(135010)
size
:
135010
type
:
"image/jpeg"
__proto__
:
Blob

Comment: showImage was manually modifying the DOM, in my example just set actual src in `readResponseAsBlob` and it will be added automatically to img src

Comment: I have updated your answer. And now it works perfectly. I wish I knew componentDidMount. Thank you so much =)